# read command doesn't wait for input

Tags: bash, wait, readline

I have problem executing a simple script in bash. The script is like this:

```
#! /bin/sh

read -p 'press  [ENTER]  to continue deleting line'
sudo sed -ie '$d' /home/hpccuser/.profile
```

and when I execute the script with ./script the output is like this:

```
press  [ENTER]  to continue deleting line./script: 3: read: arg count
[sudo] password for user
```

I run the read command directly in terminal (copy and paste from script to terminal) and it works fine; it waits for an ENTER to be hit (just like a pause).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Because your script starts with `#!/bin/sh` rather than `#!/bin/bash`, you aren't guaranteed to have bash extensions (such as `read -p`) available, and can rely only on standards-compliant functionality.

See [the relevant standards document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) for a list of functionality guaranteed to be present in `read`.

In this case, you'd probably want two lines, one doing the print, and the other doing the read:

```
printf 'press [ENTER] to continue deleting...'
read _
```

Comment: I checked and my $SHELL was bash. so /bin/sh would launch bash. am I wrong?

Comment: @mohammadhmontazeri `/bin/sh` launches whichever shell is, well, `/bin/sh` -- NOT your `$SHELL`. Moreover, starting bash as `/bin/sh` (in the case where `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `bash`) disables a great deal of functionality.

Comment: @mohammadhmontazeri See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Choose_Your_Shell for more information.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about `$REPLY` as the default variable used by `read` @CharlesDuffy!

Comment: thanks charles, using /bin/bash corrected the script. it was mentioned in last link you sent too.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem if your shell is `sh` because e.g. Dash does not allow you to call `read` without the name of a variable.

Comment: @tripleee, ooh! Quite right; thank you for the catch.

Comment: God bless you in abundance, Charles!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with echo command too!:

```
    echo "press  [ENTER]  to continue deleting line"
    read continue
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem if your shell is `sh` because e.g. Dash does not allow you to call `read` without the name of a variable.

Comment: With `echo` (unless you have one that supports `-n`, which is an optional feature shells aren't required to implement), you get an extra newline this way that isn't present with the original `read -p` code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use pipe to redirect contents to your function/script it will run your command in a sub-shell and set stdin (`0`) to a pipe, which can be checked by

```sh
$ ls -l /dev/fd/
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 May 27 14:08 0 -> pipe:[2033522138]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 27 14:08 1 -> /dev/pts/11
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 27 14:08 2 -> /dev/pts/11
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 May 27 14:08 3 -> /proc/49806/fd
```

And if you called `read`/`readarray`/... command in that function/script, the `read` command would return immediately whatever read from that pipe as the stdin has been set to that pipe rather than the tty, which explained why `read` command didn't wait for input. To make `read` command wait for input in such case you have to restore stdin to tty by `exec 0< /dev/tty` before the call to `read` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
read -p " Ici mon texte " continue
```

it works on raspbian

Comment: Entirely unhelpful.

Comment: The answerer, and those new to this community, may find it helpful to see a more thorough reason behind a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I'm late to the party, but `echo -n "Your prompt" && sed 1q` does the trick on a POSIX-compliant shell.
This prints a prompt, and grabs a line from STDIN.

Alternatively, you could expand that input into a variable:

```
echo -n "Your prompt"
YOUR_VAR=$(sed 1q)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
read -p 'press  [ENTER]  to continue deleting line' < /dev/tty
```

Forces the input to come from the terminal.

Tested/works using bash script on UBUNTU's GNOME terminal.